# How do I share a transaction across a set of parallel tasks

Tags: c#, transactions, parallel-processing, transactionscope

I have a TransactionScope object and I want to use it for all the tasks created using Parallel.ForEach, how do I achieve this?

I want to writing to a message queue in parallel, 20-50 messages, message queue is transactional:

```
 using (var queue = new MessageQueue(_exportEndpoint))
 {
      var label = string.Format("{0} ComponentId - {1}", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(), componentId);
      queue.Send(contents, label, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
      _log.WriteInfo("ExportToQueue: Message sent to queue - " + label);
 }
```

And the main thread is using a TransactionScope object, I tried the following but I get a time out on  the commit of the transaction:

```
var clone = Transaction.Current.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption.RollbackIfNotComplete);
Parallel.ForEach(components.ToList(), c => ExportComponent(c, clone));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have some example code of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorted!

I was missing a `Complete` for the DependentTransaction

Answer (score 0):

As long as those tasks participate individually with the transaction context, it is transparent.  In other words, wrap your foreach with the transaction scope and you are done.

Comment: The parallel task is attempting to write to a transactional message queue and I need the thread to be initialised with a transaction to achieve this